# Number of epochs in stats model ols package

Tags: python, linear-regression, statsmodels

How many epochs are used to calculate the results of the statsmodel ols results?https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.html
And can i control this parameter?